# laravel 4 - Input old for arrayed checkbox

Tags: php, validation, checkbox, laravel, laravel-4

I have a loop of checkboxes with multiple attributes. One content may have many attributes, so user can check more than one attribute.

**If some validation errors occurs in this form I need to pre-fetch already checked attribute.**

```
@foreach($attributes as $entry)



    <div class="check-line">

        <input type="checkbox" id="cat4" class='icheck-me' 
          name="attribute[<?php echo $entry->id; ?>]" 
            data-skin="square" 
            data-color="blue" 
            value="{{$entry->id}}" 
            <?php 
                if(Input::old('attribute['.$entry->id.']')== $entry->id) { 
                    echo 'checked="checked"'; 
                }
            ?>
        />

        <label class='inline' for="cat4">
            <strong>{{$entry->name}}</strong>
        </label>

    </div>
@endforeach
```

I tried above but no luck.. any ideas?

Comment: Seems to me like you need to search in the array: `<input type="checkbox" name="attribute[<?php echo $ii; ?>]" value="<?php echo $entry->id; ?>" <?php if (in_array($entry->id, Input::old('attribute'))) echo 'checked'; ?>>` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Laravel docs on [Requests](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input):

"When working on forms with "array" inputs, you may use dot notation to access the arrays:"

```
$input = Input::get('products.0.name');
```

So you should be able to do this fpr `Input::old()` as well:

```
<?php 
    if(Input::old('attribute.' . $ii) == $entry->id) { 
        echo 'checked="checked"'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanx a ton.. people forgot to upvote at stackoverflow these days.. i wish you will get 10 votes for this

Comment: Technically it's I don't think this is as accurate as my comment - it assumes that the checkboxes and the values are always in the same order. They probably will be, but if you change the way that `$attributes` is ordered you're probably going to have weird problems where only *some* of the checks are remembered.

Comment: @alexrussell I think you are right. Maybe add as another answer and let timus2001 mark yours as accepted? Your way is more reliable.

Comment: Hmm, actually since the author uses `name="attribute[<?php echo $ii; ?>]"` so my answer should work fine. But yes, I agree with your way nevertheless.

Comment: @Unnawut how about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364162/laravel-4-input-old-for-arrayed-checkbox/24366588#24366588)? I have a feeling that because yours is already accepted and required less work to understand and implement nothing will change, but I do like to give details and suggestions for improvements if I can. Oh well!

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more catch-all answer to this would be to do an array search rather than just checking the current index. As such, I see the code looking like this:

```
@foreach($attributes as $entry)
    <div class="check-line">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cat4_{{{ $entry->id }}}" class="icheck-me"
               name="attribute[]"
               data-skin="square"
               data-color="blue"
               value="{{{ $entry->id }}}"
               @if (in_array($entry->id, Input::old('attribute')))
                   checked
               @endif
            />

        <label class="inline" for="cat4_{{{ $entry->id }}}">
            <strong>{{{ $entry->name }}}</strong>
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

So first off I've made the code more Blade-compliant:

- Any echos are now `{{{` and `}}}` rather than the previous mix of `<?php echo ___; ?>` and `{{`/`}}` (I went for `{{{` rather than `{{` as it's not HTML being echoed and it's better to be safer)
- The `<?php if () {` is now a Blade `@if ()`

The `name` attribute is now just a standard array (doesn't include indices, as it doesn't need to), however the `id` attribute previously gave all checkboxes the same ID. While browsers will let you do this, it's technically illegal HTML, so I've appended the entry ID to each checkbox.

Finally, the if condition no longer checks that the value of the input with the current index matches the current entry's ID, but instead searches to see if the current entry's ID is *anywhere* in the returned array. This protects against the possibility of your entries being returned in a different order to the previous time they were on the page.

We now don't have a reliance on the $ii variable, so it can be removed too.

---

**Caveats:**

In doing this I've made the code a little nicer, but the code is no longer identical. Without knowing exactly why you use the $ii variable in order to provide keys to your `attribute` array I can't say that using my code will work correctly. However, assuming it was just there to help with this old input thing, then it's fine.

Also, my change of `{{` to `{{{` may have consequence I don't know about. I'd have thought for the `$entry->id` stuff it'd be fine, but maybe `$entry->name` in the `<label>` need to be unescaped HTML for a reason. Feel free to change this back.

Comment: I can tell why I rarely use {{{ ... }}}. I prefer to filter/escape data the moment it is stored. And it has always worked for me that way. In case I need to get the unescaped version, I would store both escaped and unescaped content along side. Otherwise I would have so much headache figuring out if the content was trustable, have I escaped/filtered it already or not, etc.

Comment: Ahh fair enough. I used to be an escape-on-input man, but it end up making other forms of output (say text-only emails, CSV files, etc.) really awkward as you have to now unescape things. I know it's half a dozen of one, because escaping on output you save on that headache but then you gain the "now *what* do I escape again?" headache. Plus it is very easy to triple brace those echoes, and then bam you're open to possible attacks.

Comment: (Correction to above: it's very easy to *forget* to triple brace things!)